# Binomial Distribution Problem - Desk problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am new to probability and using One of the books to learn the concepts. I got stuck in following problem.

> The mathematics department has 8 graduate assistants who are assigned
>   to the same office. Each assistant is just as likely to study at home
>   as in the office. How many desks must there be in the office so that
>   each assistant has a desk at least 90% of the time?

Probability of each student being in office is 1/2. So probability of all 8 in office is 1/256, similarly 7 in office is 8/256 etc.
But I am not able to link these information with the question of how many desks.

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Suppose the number of students in the office is $X$.  You want to determine $n$ so that $P(X \le n) \ge 0.9$.

Comment: In R statistical software 'qbinom` is a quantile function (inverse CDF): `qbinom(.9, 8, 1/2)` returns `6`. For verification using the binomial CDF: `pbinom(6, 8, 1/2)` returns `0.9648438`, but `pbinom(5, 8, 1/2)` returns only `0.8554688`. Suggest you see the Comment by @awkward, and figure out how to explain the answer in terms of the formula for the binomial PDF. (Similar to "airline overbooking problem.")